# unable to parse a webpage using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse below webpage to get name of stocks hitting now all time high or low in the exchange.

https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/HighLow.html?Flag=H#

however, when i download the webpage using beautiful soup and check the data i do not find the stock name or price mentioned in the webpage. 
I wish to write a function to download the stocks that hit a new all time high each day please help what am i missing?

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried and explain what the specific problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the HTML on the page is generated dynamically by JavaScript. You are most likely using the `requests` library, which cannot handle HTML generated in this way.

What you can do, instead, is use the [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library, which allows you to launch an instance of a web browser controlled by Python, and get the page source from there.

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = '...' # path to driver here
url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/HighLow.html?Flag=H#'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
page_source = driver.get(url).page_source
```

By parsing `page_source` with `BeautifulSoup`, you can get what you want.

Comment: thank you for the quick response however the page has 2 pages in it so 25 stocks on 1 page and 25 on another using above method i am able to parse first page only  , the url is also same if i click on second page, please help how can i solve this ?

Comment: That is a separate question, I think @AnandShukla